# Making back button and action bar back the same

Tags: android

For example, I have 2 activities which are named Main and Photos. I start Photos from Main. When I press back button when Photos activity opened, my navigation drawer menu is still selected. However, if I press back menu on action bar, Main activity refreshes, so selection disappears. I want to apply action bar back's event on back button. How can I do?

Comment: If my answer has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to make *your* action bar button implement *androids* back buttons action rather than vice-versa, however, it can be done.

```
// Newer, but Im not sure what API version it came in
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
    mMyAbBackBtn.callOnClick();
}

// Older, still supported
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == keyCode) {
        mMyAbBackBtn.callOnClick();
        return true; //handled
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "back button on action bar" is actually called an **Up button**. Just to clarify the differences: the **Back button** returns you to the previous activity (this could bring you to a different app) while the **Up button** will return you to the previous activity *in the current application*.

I'm quite confused how you have an Up button and a [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) at the same time, would you put up some screenshots?

Assuming your "navigation drawer menu" isn't a native part of android that you're talking about, I don't recommend overriding your Back button to get your desired behavior.

Instead consider overriding `onActivityCreated` or `onResume`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(); // don't restore the state
    // alternatively:
    // super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); // you may have other things you
                                                    // want to preserve
    // unSelect(); // your code to unselect whatever your navigation menu drawer is
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    unSelect(); // your code to unselect whatever your navigation menu drawer is
}
```