# Action-Bar Back key not working

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, back-button

I have made a action-bar back button in my app with:
Settings.java:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and 
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name=".Settings">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="at.mrminemeet.reviewcheck.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

but I experienced that the software-key calls the "onPause" and so but the action-bar one won't do that.

I checked some other posts and so which tell me to try

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
     // stuff
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

but it didn't do anything. It completly ignores that I added the code.

Did I do anything wrong?

Other posts:
[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081862/enable-action-bar-back-button-like-hardware-back-button)
[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358989/making-back-button-and-action-bar-back-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [`onOptionsItemSelected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html%23onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) and use the ID `android.R.id.home` to override the up botton action. What I would do is call the `onBackPressed()` function when the home button is pressed. A sample code will look like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        getActivity().onBackPressed()
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

For further details, you can see the [Android documentation on providing up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral)

Note that the answer below was written before the original question was edited. I am leaving it here and have answered the question above.

---

**Original Answer:**

If you are specifically talking about

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
     super.onBackPressed();
     // stuff
}
```

then the problem lies that you call `super.onBackPressed()` before your code. This call will go back to the previous activity or exit the app depending on which activity it is called on. Instead change it to-

@Override

```
public void onBackPressed(){
     //your code to do stuff here
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and it will first execute your code and then go back.

Comment: I put the _//stuff_ on the wrong place. It is before the `super.OnBackPressed();`

Comment: @MrMinemeet I have edited my answer to answer your question. Hope this works!